# Is there a way to read an Excel formula from a closed workbook (ADO)?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, excel-formula, ado

I'm looking for a way to get formulae from cells in a closed workbook to copy them into a new workbook. So far, I've been able to copy values of cells across but I can't figure out how to copy formulae.
So far I have been using "Recordset.GetRows()" but this just gets the value, is there a method to get the formula of a cell that I'm just not seeing or a different way entirely?
Below is the VBA code I currently have:

```
cn.ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Test 1.xlsm;" & _
    "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=NO';"

cn.Open

rs.ActiveConnection = cn

rs.Source = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
rs.Open

array_1 = rs.GetRows()
```

Thank you for any help you can offer,

Carrie

(I'm also not sure if I'll run into issues with VBA strings being limited to 255 characters and I believe some formulae will exceed that character length.)

Comment: Does the workbook reside in a cloud location like SharePoint or something or is this all completely local to your workstation?

Comment: Hi, its completely local to my workstation.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you cannot / don't want to open the workbook?

Comment: The process needs to be automated and the workbooks are very large so they are quite slow to open (about 4 mins on this machine). Using the ADO connection above, it doesnt have to open the workbooks so can search for the cells very quickly, unfortunately it is only returning the value of the cell, not cell formula.

Comment: You could look at using the OpenXML approach but may be difficult to interpret the exact formula depending on how it’s stored and that’s outside of VBA so would take more to get the result.

Comment: There is no (general) limit of 255 chars for a String in VBA. There is a limit when using a string as parameter, but you can read much longer strings into VBA using ADO. That said: I doubt that there is a way to read the formula that way - that would be the same as fetching the formula of a calculated column from SQL Server.